# Is it possible to select tests annotated with combination of tags in JUnit5/Gradle?

Tags: gradle, tags, junit5

Let's say the tests are tagged `"slow","fast","ui","api"` (among others). So some tests may be tagged "fast" and "api", and some "fast" and "ui"

How can I select the tests tagged both "fast" and "api"?

```
includeTags: "fast","api"
```

will  run all fast tests (even "ui") and all "api" tests (even "slow").

Would be nice to have something like:

```
includeAllTheTags: "fast","api"
```

for that.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag expressions to the rescue!

> Tag expressions are boolean expressions with the operators `!`, `&` and `|`. In addition, `(` and `)` can be used to adjust for operator precedence.

Find more details and samples at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions

For Gradle, it could read like

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'fast & api'
    }
}
```

Source: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in [the JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions):

```
includeTags("fast & api")
```